# Check jquery array had incremnt values or decrement values

Tags: jquery, loops

I have jQuery array that contains fixed 4 value.
and i need function to check that in array values is increment or decrement.
like below eg.:

```
    Var Array = [1,3,4,9]; => function Returns: Increment
    Var Array = [9,6,4,2]; => function Returns: Decrement
    Var Array = [7,9,2,6]; => function Returns: None
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you post your code?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-array-forms-an-increasing-decreasing-sequence-or-vice-versa/ tried code from here

Answer (score 1):

```js
let ex1 = [1,3,4,9]
let ex2 = [9,6,4,2]
let ex3 = [7,9,2,6]


console.log(incrementOrDecrement(ex1))
console.log(incrementOrDecrement(ex2))
console.log(incrementOrDecrement(ex3))



function incrementOrDecrement(array) {
  let toCheck = ''

  // Check first two numbers
   if (array[0] === array[1]) {
    return 'None'
  }

  if (array[0] < array[1]) {
    toCheck = 'Increment'
  }

  if (array[0] > array[1]) {
    toCheck = 'Decrement'
  }

  // Loop rest of array to check whether it's sequential
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (toCheck === 'Increment') {
      if (array[i] >= array[i + 1]){
      return 'None'
    }
  }

    if (toCheck === 'Decrement') {
      if (array[i] <= array[i + 1]){
      return 'None'
    }
  }


  }
  return toCheck

}
```